# How do I view base64 pdf files from mongodb database which are above 1mb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

```
//app.js
const express=require("express");
const app=express();
const bodyParser=require("body-parser");
const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');
const base64 = require('file-base64');
const File=require("./models/file");
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/filesDB',{useNewUrlParser: true,useUnifiedTopology:true});
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.once('error', (err)=>{
    console.log(err);
});
db.on("open", ()=>{
    console.log("database connection success");
})
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set("view engine","ejs");
app.use(expressLayouts);
const applicationMimeTypes=["application/pdf"];
// app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: "5mb",extended: false}));
// app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: "5mb"}));
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: "5mb"}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: "5mb",extended: true,parameterLimit: 5000}));
app.get("/",async(req,res,next)=>{
  try{
    const files=await File.find();
    res.render("layout", {
      files
    });
  }catch (err){
    console.log("err: "+ err);
  }
});
app.post("/add", async (req,res)=>{
  const file=req.body.fileUpload;
  const fileName=req.body.fileName;
  const files=new File({
    fileName
  });
  saveFile(files,file);
  try{
    const newFile=await files.save();
    res.redirect('/')  ;
  }catch (err){
    console.log(err);
  }
});
function saveFile(File,fileEncoded){
  if(fileEncoded===null) return;
  const file=JSON.parse(fileEncoded);
  if(file!==null && applicationMimeTypes.includes(file.type)){
    File.file=new Buffer.from(file.data,"base64");
    File.fileType=file.type;
  }
}
app.listen(3000 || process.env.PORT,function(req,res){
  console.log("Server is up and listening");
})

//layout.ejs
<%- include("partials/header"); -%>
  <form action="/add" method="post">
    <label for="fileName">File Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="fileName">
    <label for="fileUpload">File Upload</label>
    <input type="file" name="fileUpload" class="filepond">
    <button type="submit" name="button">Upload</button>
  </form>
  <% if(files) { %>
            <% files.forEach(m => { %>
              <embed type="application/pdf" src="<%= m.coverApplicationPath %>" width="300" height="300">
            <% }) %>
    <% } %>
<%- include("partials/footer"); -%>

//file.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const fileSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
  file:{
    type:Buffer,
    required:true
  },
  fileType:{
    type:String,
    required:true
  },
  fileName:{
    type:String,
    required:true
  }
});
fileSchema.virtual('coverApplicationPath').get(function (){
    if(this.file != null && this.fileType != null){
        return `data:${this.fileType};charset=utf-8;base64,${this.file.toString("base64")}`;
    }
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('files', fileSchema);
```

If someone wants to see other necessary files do let me know, I am able to embed pdf file under 1mb but files above 1mb gets saved in database but I am not able to show it on client side. I tried using GridFS but using it I am only able to upload but not embed nor download it. Any help is appreciated. Thank You

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The code contains various parts that make the program works like how the file is being stored how app.js works and how the form is passing information to app.js so I can't cut short or trim the code, it's for easier understanding of anyone who wishes to help me out with my problem.